# TYPO3 - Fluid returns the string "array"

Tags: typo3, fluid

I have this in my template:

```
<v:iterator.explode content="<f:format.nl2br>{artnumbers.qualitynumber.certificates}</f:format.nl2br>" glue="<br />" as="expCertificates">
```

if artnumbers.qualitynumber.certificates is empty, it returns teh string "array".

Is that a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the <f:format.nl2br> ViewHelper. This ViewHelper replaces newlines in a string (!) with 
 tags. You cannot use it for an array and that's why it returns "array".

I don't know why you need the explode viewHelper. Why don't you just iterate through your certificates?

```
<f:for each="{artnumbers.qualitynumber.certificates}" as="certificate">
    {certificate}<br />
</f:for>
```

**EDIT**: If certificates is a string containing newlines, use the newline as glue for explode:

```
<v:iterator.explode content="{artnumbers.qualitynumber.certificates}" glue="\n" as="expCertificates">
```

You could also try to use CONSTANT:LF in glue as suggested in the documentation of the ViewHelper.

Comment: My certificates are written in a textbox with one certificate per line. Therefore I need to explode by newline.

Answer (score 3):

`v:iterator.explode` when used with the `as` argument implies the variable assigned to `as` is only available inside the tag content:

`<v:iterator.explode content="1,2,3" as="numbers">
    {numbers} is an array
</v:iterator.explode>
{numbers} is no longer defined.`

This behaviour changed from VHS 1.7 to 1.8 (from memory).

Alternatively, do:

`{artnumbers.qualitynumber.certificates
    -> f:format.nl2br()
    -> v:iterator.explode(glue: '<br />')
    -> v:var.set(name: 'extractedCertificates')}
<f:for each="{extractedCertificates}" as="certificate">
    {certificate}
</f:for>`

Or better, but assumes your lines are ONLY separated by a single line break:

`{artnumbers.qualitynumber.certificates
    -> v:iterator.explode(glue: 'constant:LF')
    -> v:var.set(name: 'extractedCertificates')}
<f:for each="{extractedCertificates}" as="certificate">
    {certificate}
</f:for>`

Which of course lets you skip the `nl2br` step.

Even more compacted:

`<f:for each="{artnumbers.qualitynumber.certificates -> v:iterator.explode(glue: 'constant:LF')}" as="certificate">
    {certificate}
</f:for>`