# Typo3 Fluid separating a string into elements to be able to compare

Tags: typo3, fluid

It's the first time I am using fluid.

**The challenge:**
In a form I am trying to mark those fields (highlighting or indicator) which are mandatory.
The mandatory fields are provided as a string (within an array  `{settings.registration.requiredFields}`)

**The approach**
I thought a can create a partial to which I pass the current field-name and compare this fieldname against the list of requiredFields.

**The issue**

1) I found out that partial strings can not be compared.

2) So I thought to explode the string with an `v:interator.explode` into an array which than can be compared with an `f:for` and the marking done there, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287348/typo3-fluid-returns-the-string-array)

After some hours of earching an googling I have now found out that I need to add the `vhs` and `flux` extensions. With no success.

In the output the statement are shown instead of the results.

```
<v:iterator.explode content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam" glue=" " as="bar">
                <div class="event-registration-value event-title">

                </div>
            </v:iterator.explode>
```

from the (test)input

```
          <v:iterator.explode content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam" glue=" " as="bar">
            <div class="event-registration-value event-title">
                {bar}
            </div>

        </v:iterator.explode>
```

What do I need to do to get this running?

PS: I am using typo3 7.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `v:` functions running there are two important things to do:

1. Include the vhs extension from the TER
2. define the namespace

The namespace is defined by adding

```
 {namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
```

on top of the file.

**Hint:**

If the template breaks after this addition, it might not be the `namespace` line, but instead a typo in the `<v:...>` statements.

In my case it was a missing ending `"` and missing `{}` around same variables.

*As a newbie took me three days to solve.*

Answer (score 0):

As you do not mention any extension for the form I assume, that you just creating your own, in such case you can easily add your own ViewHelper as well which will do exactly what you need i.e.:

**somewhere in your TypoScript**:

```
plugin.tx_myext.settings.registration.requiredFields = foo bar baz
```

**typo3conf/ext/myext/Classes/ViewHelpers/IsFieldRequiredViewHelper.php**:

```php
<?php
namespace Vendor\Myext\ViewHelpers;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

class IsFieldRequiredViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractConditionViewHelper {

    /**
     * @param string $fieldName Current field name
     * @param string $requiredFields List of required names separated by spaces
     *
     * @return string the rendered string
     */
    public function render($fieldName, $requiredFields) {
        $requiredArray = GeneralUtility::trimExplode(' ', $requiredFields, true);

        return (in_array($fieldName, $requiredArray))
            ? $this->renderThenChild()
            : $this->renderElseChild();
    }
}
```

**So in your Fluid template you can use it in several ways, several samples:**

```html
{namespace myvhs=Vendor\Myext\ViewHelpers}


<!-- 1: Use your condition with then/else blocks -->
<myvhs:isFieldRequired
        fieldName="foo"
        requiredFields="{settings.registration.requiredFields}">

    <f:then>This field IS required</f:then>
    <f:else>It's optional...</f:else>

</myvhs:isFieldRequired>

<!-- 2: or just with `then` implicit block: -->
<myvhs:isFieldRequired
        fieldName="bar"
        requiredFields="{settings.registration.requiredFields}">Fill the bellow input...</myvhs:isFieldRequired>

<!-- 3: Add `required-field` class inline -->
<input type="text" class="{myvhs:isFieldRequired(fieldName: 'baz', requiredFields: settings.registration.requiredFields, then: 'required-field')}">
```

(*note that you of course need to change the Vendor and extension name to fit your current situation*)

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to adopt the [Event Registration](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/sf_event_mgt)

The settings is already there.

Comment: In such case you can create a simple extension exactly for your needs with Extension Builder: https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder and add the mentioned ViewHelper there (note: you can use custom ViewHelpers within templates of other extensions the same way as in own exts)

Comment: BTW, shouldn't the fields be separated by comma in this ext? (just shooting as watching it's code)